# php symfony parsing & joining url

Tags: php, symfony, url, twig

I need to reconstruct url redirecting using php, symfony & twig (I know nobody is doing like this anymore), anyways, this is where I am struggling:
I parsed old URL so it gives me array of data, now I need to add new query parameters by adding them to array, then I have to pass array by `joinUrl` which will return me brand new url.
For now, I redirect user just to new page without query parameters. I need to pass query params as well somehow. My code so far:

```
    $parsed = $this->get('parser_url')->parseUrl('http://website.com/');

    $newPreviewUrl = $this->get('parser_url')->joinUrl($parsed);
    $parsed['query']= $page->getId();

    return $this->redirect($newPreviewUrl);
```

What I get from symfony debugger:

```
DefaultController.php on line 158:
array:11 [▼
  "scheme" => "http"
  "user" => null
  "pass" => null
  "host" => "website.com"
  "subdomain" => null
  "domain" => "website.com"
  "port" => null
  "path" => "/"
  "query" => 11
  "fragment" => null
  "registrable" => true
]
```

Thanks for any help. I am just a beginner in back-end stuff.

Comment: The dump from the line #158, what is that? The `$newPreviewUrl`?

Comment: Well, from what you said, you are using an url to send the user to, without the query, but provided you do have the query parameters somewhere, you can use the http_build_query function from PHP for that.

Comment: @JovanPerovic array which I got from $parsed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as you said, you are redirecting the user to a new page without query parameters.

You just need to use this url then and concatenate with the `http_build_query()` output:

```
$adaptedUrl = $baseUrl . '?' . http_build_query($queryParametersArray);
```

It's not very clear for me what are the parameters you are sending though, but they should follow something close to this format:

```
$queryParametersArray = array(
    'foo' => 'bar',
    'baz' => 'boom',
    'cow' => 'milk',
    'php' => 'hypertext processor'
);
```

Which will result in a string like this from this function:

```
foo=bar&baz=boom&cow=milk&php=hypertext+processor
```

The example is a courtesy from the [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) documentation. :)

Comment: I already tried this one, it wasn't correct
$newPreviewUrl = $this->get('parser_url')->joinUrl($parsed, UrlParserService::URL_QUERY) . http_build_query($data);
I don't have to use  http_build_query at all. parseUrl divides URL into array, I have to change on of the elements and pass new array to joinUrl which will return me URL string

Comment: What's the output of the that statement? The example you gave is different than this one.

Comment: the output of code I wrote above is giving error: Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given

Comment: @Liana, the method `in_array()` is not written anywhere in the example you gave. The first example in your question is: $newPreviewUrl = ... **->joinUrl($parsed);** and on this comment you wrote $newPreviewUrl = ... **->joinUrl($parsed, UrlParserService::URL_QUERY)**. Do you understand why I am confused?

Comment: ok, sorry for this. This is what I am passing right now: $newPreviewUrl = $this->get('parser_url')->joinUrl($parsed) . http_build_query($data);
AND $data is:
$data = array(
            'url' => $test->getTestingUrl(),
            'isPreview' => 'true',
            'device' => $test->getDeviceType(),
            'injectJs' => array($jQueryUrl, $pageJs),
        );
When running, I get 404 not found

Comment: Test one thing at a time, see what you get, but for the sake of the example, try using this first: `$newPreviewUrl = $this->get('parser_url')->joinUrl($parsed) . '?' . http_build_query(['testing123'=> '123', 'testingAbc' => 'abc']);` then echo what's the output of this to check what's being returned.